# Does the recovery partition get updates?

Tags: recovery

I clean-installed Mountain Lion 10.8.0. Now I am at 10.8.2 and I want to do a clean install again. If I boot to the recovery partition and do a restore, will I have 10.8.0 or 10.8.2? Does the recovery partition get updated when OS X gets updated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Recovery Partition **does not** get updated. Once the partition is created, *OS X Recovery* downloads the latest of your OS X version from Apple.

Extracted from Apple's **[About OS X Recovery](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718)**:

> Reinstalling OS X Lion or OS X Mountain Lion via OS X Recovery requires broadband access to the Internet via Wi-Fi or an Ethernet connection. OS X is downloaded over the Internet from Apple when OS X Recovery is used for reinstallation.

Comment: cool. so its better to download it and clean install it, so i can use my mac while its downloading. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the local recovery partition is updated when you upgrade your OS. Whereas Internet Recovery will download the original OS version that came with your Mac.

http://osxdaily.com/2014/12/14/reinstall-os-x-mac-internet-recovery/

https://www.lifewire.com/identify-os-x-version-on-recovery-hd-partition-2259968